# Why did Winn Adami handle Bajor foreign affairs despite not being First Minister?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, politics

In DS9 Season 3, elections are held for the Premiership/First-Ministership of Bajor, and Winn Adami is a candidate - wishing to secure political as well as spiritual/cultural leadership of the planet. She eventually withdraws from the race in favor of Shakaar, who gets elected.

And yet - in several later episodes, we see Winn, rather than First Minister Shakaar, lead political negotiations with other civilizations, like the Federation, the Cardasians or the Dominion, and make decisions regarding peace agreements, non-aggression pacts and the like.

Isn't that inconsistent with her not being [First Minister](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_minister)? I mean, theoretically, it could  be that she's a member of the council, say ex oficio, and appointed Minister of Foreign Affairs - but there was no mention of any of that, nor does this role suit a woman of the cloth (as opposed to, say, Minister of Culture, of Education, of Religious Affairs etc.)

Comment: The pope used to direct nations to war.

Comment: @Valorum: Direction in fiery speeches and consultations is one thing, but she seems to be simply and literally holding political power.

Comment: That's because she is holding political power. During the occupation, future kai Winn was a rebel and a popular one at that. But I feel you are approaching this from the wrong viewpoint. Bajor's government is not as secular as our modern governments. It is pretty much a theocracy for most of the show.

Comment: @jo1storm: 1. If that were the case, she would not need to run for First Minister to begin with. 2. Popularity is not the point. Opaka was even more popular, and she did not manage Bajor's foreign affairs.

Comment: @einpoklum There were no Bajor's foreign affairs while Opaka was kai. Bajor is a society which just got out of occupation and is still trying to figure itself out. Before the occupation, Bajor was pure theocracy. A couple hundred years ago, there was even a caste system. As one of things they have to accomplish to be considered for Federation membership, they have to become democracy. That means elections. That doesn't mean that a priest can't run for government position,they just have to be democratically chosen.

Comment: @jo1storm: There were lots and lots of foreign affairs when the occupation ended - like the forming of relations with the federation.

Comment: @einpoklum: there were, but there done by provisional government, which had both members of the clergy and rebels in it. Just why do you think Sisko had to be accepted as "The Emissary of the Prophets" for DS9 agreement to work? We don't know who did the negotiations.

Comment: @jo1storm: What's your reference for their being Vedeks on the provisional government? Of course the government is _influenced_ by the religious establishment, but that's not the same as the Kai and the vedeks governing themselves.